# Restrict the user to type more than maxLength extjs Combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs5, extjs6

I have a combobox with a tpl I wanted to restrict the user not to type more than 8 chars. How can I achieve it as combobox doesn't have enforceMaxLength and maxLength only give a tool tip but allows the user to type the characters more than the maxLength.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vam

Comment: The combobox does have `enforceMaxLength` in version 6.2 and at least as far back as version 4.1.1. See modified fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1var)

Comment: Thanks chrisuae it worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Ext.form.field.ComboBox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) derives from [`Ext.form.field.Text`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html), so for all config options available on the `textfield`, you can check whether `combobox` really had to override them in a breaking manner, or whether they are still working. Most of them, if not all, should still be available, even if not part of the combobox documentation.

As user chrisuae already pointed out in a comment, `enforceMaxLength` is still working in `combobox`. This is because `combobox` does not remove any of the two parts required intact for maxLength to be available, [`Ext.form.field.Base.fieldSubTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Base.js-3.html#Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-fieldSubTpl) or [`Ext.form.field.Text.getSubTplData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Text.js.html#line625).

You may find in the `combobox` source code that [`getSubTplData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/ComboBox.js.html#line754) has been overridden, but the line `data = me.callParent([fieldData]);` means that the original code is still executed.

Comment: Thanks Alexander I didn't try with enforceMaxLength for combobox I just went through the documentation. thank you

Comment: can you help me with this issue @Alexander http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938907/how-to-clear-reset-the-panels-in-a-accordion-on-change-of-records-in-a-grid-extj